# Can a floating-point conversion cause undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, floating-point, language-lawyer

A floating-point conversion, as the standard defines it, is a conversion between two floating-point types that isn't a promotion.

The simplest example is `double` to `float`:

```
double d = 0.1;
float f = d;
```

The standard says [[conv.double]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/conv.double):

> A prvalue of floating-point type can be converted to a prvalue of another floating-point type.
> If the source value can be exactly represented in the destination type, the result of the conversion is that exact representation.
> If the source value is between two adjacent destination values, the result of the conversion is an implementation-defined choice of either of those values.
> Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.
> The conversions allowed as floating-point promotions are excluded from the set of floating-point conversions.

In my example above, the source value cannot be exactly represented in the destination type. The value of `d` is `0.10000000000000001`, whereas the value of `f` is (likely) `0.10000000149011612`, and indeed if you cast `f` back to a `double`, is doesn't equal `d`. However, this source value is between two adjacent destination values: `f` and the previous representable `float` value, `0.099999994039535522`. So the value of `f` can be either of these values, but because `0.10000000149011612` is closer to `0.10000000000000001` than `0.099999994039535522` is, that's likely the value chosen by the implementation.

My question is about the last case:

> Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Are there any values for which a conversion is undefined behavior? Since floating-point types have representations for +infinity and -infinity, I would assume there cannot be any source value that isn't exactly represented or between two adjacent destination values: any `double` value is either an exact `float` value (including `NaN`) or between -infinity and +infinity, in which case it is between two adjacent `float` values.

So what is the point of this "otherwise" case? Is it here to cover exotic types that are considered floating-point but aren't `float`, `double`, or `long double`? Can a conversion between `float`, `double`, and `long double` cause undefined behavior?

Comment: IANALL, the "Otherwise, the behavior is undefined." can be *implementation* defined (well-defined), as an **extension** to the standard.  Which may make your program have reliable, predictable behavior on your platform, but may not be as portable as one might prefer (which might bite you in the future, as it has me).

Comment: @Eljay The question isn't "what does undefined behavior mean", it's "how can you possibly get to that case that says it's undefined behavior".

Comment: The C++ standard does not demand that every floating point type support `+inf` or `-inf` or `NaN`.  I suspect this "undefined" clause would handle a hypothetical platform where a `double` holding infinity is converted to a `float` that doesn't support infinity.

Comment: `float` and `double` don't have to be IEEE 754 floating point types.  Not sure if there is a different encoding out there where you would fall into the UB case but the standard is codified with what the behavior is in such a case that there is ab exception.

Comment: @DrewDormann Ok I realized that by looking at [`std::numeric_limits<T>::has_infinity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/has_infinity). Any example of floating-point types that do not support infinities? Even just a large `double` (not +inf) converted to a `float` without +inf would end up in this case.

Comment: Basically, with current types of floating points, any double value is either represented by a float value or falls between two float values. Although sometimes the values gotta be `-inf`, `inf`, or `nan`.

Comment: @Nelfeal I've worked on hardware that doesn't quite meet IEEE-754 compliance, but I've never seen a floating point type that can't store infinity.  Because of this "undefined" clause, if such hardware were invented tomorrow, a conforming C++ compiler could be created for that hardware.

Comment: [MBF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Binary_Format) doesn't support -inf, +inf, or nan.  Not sure I've seen MBF ever in a C++ program, even from the olden days.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out some floating-point implementations cannot represent infinities. [MBF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Binary_Format), as Eljay pointed out, is one of them. It's also implied by the existence of [`HUGE_VAL`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/HUGE_VAL), which is the same as [`INFINITY`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/INFINITY) if possible.

However, this is extremely unlikely, and can be tested with `std::numeric_limits<T>::has_infinity`. Presumably, if this value is true, then there cannot be any undefined behavior with floating-point conversions.

Answer (score 0):

> Can a floating-point conversion cause undefined behavior?

Yes.

---

Consider 2 `float` values: `FLT_MAX` and `nextafterf(FLT_MAX, 0)`.  Their difference is `delta`. All saved in a `double`.

`random(a, b)` forms a `double` random value (a, b].

```
double max = FLT_MAX;
double max_before = nextafterf(FLT_MAX, 0);
double delta = max - max_before;

// Conversion to `float` is well defined
double in_between = max_before + random(0.0, delta);
float in_betweenf = in_between;  // in_between is inclusively between 2 float.

// Conversion to `float` can fail as the `double` value can
// exceed FLT_MAX, even is the sum is the smallest `double` more than `FLT_MAX`.
double in_between = max + random(0.0, delta);
float in_betweenf = in_between;
```

This is primarily the case when `float` does not support *infinity*.

> If the value being converted is outside the range of values that can be represented, the behavior is undefined.  C17dr § 6.3.1.5 1.

---

Ideally it would be nice if `in_between = max_before + delta + random(0.0, 0.5*delta);` was well defined, but it is not when `float` lacks an infinity.

Comment: I don't understand the point of all that code. Wouldn't something like `float f = FLT_MAX + 1` fail the same way?

Comment: @Nelfeal Not likely.  The sum `FLT_MAX + 1` may round to `FLT_MAX` and assigning that to `f` is fine.  The key to demo the problem is to use a sum. with `double` math, that exceeds `FLT_MAX` after the rounding step.

Comment: Ok, because `FLT_MAX` is a `float` so there is no conversion, but what about `FLT_MAX + 1.0`? Or `static_cast<double>(FLT_MAX) + 1`?

Comment: @Nelfeal The sum of both of those is usually `FLT_MAX`, as a `double`.  Conversion then to `float` is not a problem.

Comment: Ok, my fault for not thinking these expressions through, they don't illustrate the point I'm trying to make. What about `2*static_cast<double>(FLT_MAX)` or literally any `double` value greater than `FLT_MAX`?

Comment: @Nelfeal, when any `double > FLT_MAX` is converted to `float`, the result is UB when `float` lacks an infinity.  Otherwise the conversion has implementation defined behavior